Failed to attach to process when running widget extension on macOS
I recieve the error "Failed to attach to process" while trying to run widget extension in Xcode 15.

The problem was that I have the app also being installed through TestFlight on my machine which caused debugger to try to attach to it instead of my xcode build and fail.
Just remove the TestFlight version of the app and it'll succesfully run the extension.
Make sure you remove it correctly by removing all related files. Either search by the name of your app and delete files or use some uninstaller app for mac.
